# getIntent() not Working on my SecondActivity and EXITS when clicked

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**I have a MainActivity and has a button "Add" that should send to the SecondActivity(which has a Tablayout and fragments). The code below is the launchSecondActivty() method.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        String et_title = title.getText().toString();
        String et_room = room.getText().toString();
        String et_code = code.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, et_title);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, et_room);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, et_code);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_REQUEST);
```

**And this is on my SecondActivity onCreate() method.**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
```

**This will work perfectly. But when I add the code for the fragments,**

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_days);
        tabMon = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.itm_mon);
        tabTue = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.itm_tue);
        tabWed = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.itm_wed);
        tabThu = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.itm_thu);
        tabFri = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.itm_fri);
        tabSat = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.itm_sat);
        tabSun = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.itm_sun);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        pagerAdapter = new com.example.timetable2.PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                if(tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else if(tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else if(tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else if(tab.getPosition() == 3) {
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else if(tab.getPosition() == 4) {
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else if(tab.getPosition() == 5) {
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else if(tab.getPosition() == 6){
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    }
```

**Here is the crash log.**

```
2020-12-13 02:16:47.064 6449-6449/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.timetable2, PID: 6449
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.timetable2/com.example.timetable2.SecondActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 cannot be cast to androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3654)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 cannot be cast to androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        at com.example.timetable2.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3629)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

**This doesn't work anymore. Please help for my project. Beginner here. :((**

Comment: Add the crash log.

Comment: @PrinceAli done

Comment: The crash tells you what is wrong. ```java.lang.ClassCastException``` ViewPager2 cannot be cast to ViewPager. So in the xml file use the ViewPager not ViewPager2

Comment: Thank you so muuuch! Its fixed thanks to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I helped in a comment, but to give this question an answer, here's a brief solution:
`java.lang.ClassCastException` gets thrown when you try to cast a class to a different class. In your case, you are casting the `ViewPager2` to `ViewPager`. So in your xml file, you need to use `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager`.